# jQuery menu not hidden completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

So I have a menu, when you click a button it opens a Lightbox full of links. The Lightbox is supposed to show only when the button is clicked, but unfortunately a small portion (about 183px depending on screen size) shows at the very bottom of the page.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#trigger, .lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox').toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none
}


/* Button */

button#trigger {
  margin: 20px;
}

button#trigger {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button#trigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

#menu .lightbox {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.85;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 35% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menu .lightbox li.current_page_item a {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#menu .lightbox li.current_page_item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .lightbox a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu .lightbox a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu .lightbox.close {
  height: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

#menu .ion-android-menu {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#menu .ion-android-close {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top: 18px;
}

#menu .ion-android-close:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <button id="trigger"><span class="ion-android-menu"><!-- --></span>
    </button>
  <div class="lightbox close">
    <span class="ion-android-close"><!-- --></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Is there something I am missing? Not sure why it's there. This is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/9dftx1vg/1/

I'm pretty sure this is something simple, just can't quite put my finger on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the lightbox CSS rule, otherwise the 35% top padding  it has are *added*  to the * height: 0*  in the "hidden" state.

Comment: I actually have box-sizing: border-box on my parent css sheet, this is an import. But even when I add it directly to the Lightbox element the issues persists. What fixed it for me was taking the padding off the menu element and creating a #menu ul css addition with the padding - that way the padding is only affecting the list and not the entire Lightbox. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wdo42nr/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#trigger, .lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox').toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none
}


/* Button */

button#trigger {
  margin: 20px;
}

button#trigger {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button#trigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

#menu .lightbox {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.85;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 35% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menu .lightbox li.current_page_item a {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#menu .lightbox li.current_page_item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .lightbox a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu .lightbox a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu .lightbox.close {
  display: none;
}

#menu .ion-android-menu {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#menu .ion-android-close {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top: 18px;
}

#menu .ion-android-close:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <button id="trigger"><span class="ion-android-menu"><!-- --></span>
    </button>
  <div class="lightbox close">
    <span class="ion-android-close"><!-- --></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Just add display none to lightbox when closed

Comment: This works too! I did not select it as the answer though because the padding was actually causing the issue, meaning the other answer got to the root of the problem. Thank you for your update, I have included it in my code - in addition to adding the padding to my list to make absolutely certain the Lightbox does not display until I click the button! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be the easy one, if you add `width:0;` on `#menu .lightbox.close` style rule.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#trigger, .lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox').toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none
}


/* Button */

button#trigger {
  margin: 20px;
}

button#trigger {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button#trigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

#menu .lightbox {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.85;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 35% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menu .lightbox li.current_page_item a {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#menu .lightbox li.current_page_item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .lightbox a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu .lightbox a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu .lightbox.close {
  height: 0;
  width:0; /*ADD THIS ONE*/
  top: 100%;
}

#menu .ion-android-menu {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#menu .ion-android-close {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top: 18px;
}

#menu .ion-android-close:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <button id="trigger"><span class="ion-android-menu"><!-- --></span>
    </button>
  <div class="lightbox close">
    <span class="ion-android-close"><!-- --></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```